# Choosing a storage layer for time series data at rest

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hdfs, impala, bigdata

I am new to the big-data tech stack in general. I am implementing a real time analytics infrastructure that will ingest high volume/velocity data from different services in our micro services backend. The ingested data ( and data stream ) will be used to populate dashboards for key business metrics and for BI queries and machine learning.

All of the backend services write the data events into a Kafka cluster that is now in place. I started working on a Spark prototype to read the data from the Kafka cluster and enrich/process it.

Now i am working on where to store the data at rest. I know for real time analytics Technologies like Vertica and Terradata are fairly popular. But they have non-trivial capital investment upfront.

So i am trying to stick to open source. After a bit of study i decided to use HDFS/Impala for the data at rest and running SQL on Hadoop for our real time BI queries.

I then started thinking if instead of using HDFS/Impala, it makes more sense to use Cassandra for storing our data at rest. Cassandra scales out and has fast writes and reads. I also read some literature where people gave good arguments for using C* for such use.

Any comment/feedback is welcome.

Comment: I am falling in the same problem as you right now and it has been 2 years since you asked this question, can I know your current experience and what you used eventually?

Answer (score 5):

We store petabytes of expiring time series data in Cassandra, and we're very happy with it. In the ingestion pipeline, we're capable of many millions of writes per second, and reading is fast (sub-millisecond) for displaying/BI. For large ML tasks, you can run spark on top of Cassandra for analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jeffjirsa . So are using *just* Cassandra as storage for your Data warehouse ? How do you address schema evolution in Cassandra ?

Comment: Schema evolution? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey @jeffjirsa - I meant what if the structure of your json events that you want to end up in your data warehouse changes over time. Do you just update your Cassandra schema ?

Comment: If you use cassandra as naive key->value (partition key and no cluster keys), then you just shove the json blob in and no big deal. If you use clustering, then yes, you ALTER your cassandra schema if you add or remove fields.

Comment: Thanks again @jeffjirsa. Thats what i thought would be the way to go if we want to support schema evolution. I think i am going to go with a dual write system. Write to Cassandra for our normal real time analytics. But also write to HDFS for log storage to do more offline analytics or if we ever want to reprocess events of a time window. Here is the article that explains the approach

http://www.svds.com/flexible-data-architecture-with-spark-cassandra-and-impala/

Comment: What do you use to visualize your data stored in Cassandra ? Tableau/Spark/C* combo ? That is another thing i am looking at as i am evaluating the two options.